# Java, create a cache of re-usable thread unsafe objects

Tags: java, caching

Sometimes in java I have objects that are thread unsafe and expensive to create. I would like to create a cache of those objects so I don't need to re-create them but it must also prevent concurrent access to the same object.

For example I might have `DateFormat` and creating it is too expensive, but I can't share a single `DateFormat`. For arguments sake assume that I can't use a thread safe `DateFormat`.

What would be fantastic is to be able to create some cache like this:

```
Cache<DateFormat> cache = new Cache(() -> dateFormatCreator());
// and now make use of a dateFormat that might be created for this call 
// or it might be an existing one from the cache.
cache.withExclusiveAccessToObject(dateFormat -> {
   // use the dateFormat here, it is not in use by any other thread at the same time.
   // new dateFormats can be created on the fly as needed.
});
```

I should have also mentioned that `ThreadLocal` is not ideal as I can not ensure threads are going to be re-used.

Comment: Is there a question? / For just one small object, you can just use a `ThreadLocal` (about the only good use for them).

Comment: It sounds like you want an object pool, e.g. [Vibur](https://github.com/vibur/vibur-object-pool) and [Stormpot](https://github.com/chrisvest/stormpot).

Comment: Nice one @BenManes now I am spoiled for choice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two paths you can go:

**Option 1**

Maintain an object-per-thread

This can work if you access the expensive object from a limited well defined set of threads (read, using a thread-pool and not creating threads every time, which is what happens anyway in many applications).

In this case you can use a `ThreadLocal`. Since within one thread everything is expected to be sequential, you can keep thread-unsafe objects in a thread local.

You can think of ThreadLocal as a map that per thread maintains a dedicated instance of an expensive object.

**Option 2**

Share one (or N in general) objects between M threads so that N < M. In this case there might be a situation where two threads will try to work with the same object.

I'm not aware of ready solution for this, after all its your objects that you want to maintain, but in general its pretty easy to wrap your own implementation that will provide some sort of locking/synchronized access to the objects for your types of objects.

The range of ideas for implementations can vary. As an idea: You can wrap an actual object with a runtime/build-time generated proxy making it effectively thread safe:

```
public interface IMyObject {
    void inc();
    void dec();
}

// this is an object that you would like to make thread safe
public class MyActualObject implements IMyObject {
    private int counter = 0;
    void inc() {counter++;}
    void dec() {counter--;}
}

public class MyThreadSafeProxy implements IMyObject {

    private IMyObject realObject;

    public MyThreadSafeProxy(IMyObject realObject) {
        this.realObject = realObject;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void inc() {
       realObject.inc();
    }

    @Override 
    public syncrhonized void dec() {
       realObject.dec();
    }
}
```

Instead of storing `MyObject`-s you can wrap them in `MyThreadSafeProxy`

Its possible also to generate such a proxy automatically: See [cglib](https://www.baeldung.com/cglib) framework or [Dynamic Proxies (java.lang.Proxy class)](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies)

From my experience usually Option 1 is preferable unless the objects you work with are too expensive so that if there are N threads in the pool, you can't really support N objects in memory.